# Why is there no space behind closing quotation mark in enumeration?

Tags: spacing, punctuation

I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\newcommand{\add}{$\oplus$\space}
\newcommand{\ent}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Content: \add \ent{"Node add form" base form}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, there's no spacing after the closing quotation mark in the enumeration. How can I solve this?

Comment: You're not using the correct form for quotation marks.  It should be `` to open and ' ' to close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Never use `"` for quotes. In particular, languages where `babel` uses `"` as a shorthand will make straight double quotes fail in various ways. The correct form is

```
Content: \add \ent{``Node add form'' base form}
```

or, with Unicode characters

```
Content: \add \ent{“Node add form” base form}
```

---

Why `"` mustn't be used for quotes? It's true that what's printed is, sometimes, the glyph ”, but this character usually has no setting of the `\sfcode`, which means wrong spacing at sentence ending periods that are typed (as normal in American typography) before the closing quotes.

But the biggest problem is with `babel` and the many languages for which `"` is used as a shorthand. The mechanism uses `\@ifnextchar` and so spaces are ignored after the character, which is exactly what happens in the example.

None of these problems happens when `''` or `”` are used (the latter of course requires a suitable call of `inputenc`). Good editors can be set up so that typing `"` triggers a proper action. For instance, with Emacs and AUCTeX, typing `"` will produce ``` `` ``` if after a space (or at the beginning of a line), `''` otherwise; typing another `"` produces a *single* `"`.

Comment: Only +1, but ``Never use " for quotes'' deserves much more!

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke What more? *Never* is used in its precise meaning: “don't use `"` for typesetting quotes, in any case whatsoever”. ;-)

Comment: @egreg I mean: much more than only one upvote. It is so horrible mistake, that reminding about it should be additionally honoured.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why we shall not use ". (babel transforms " to an active character, etc., i.e. a command that eats spaces). Just a suggestion =8-)

Comment: @egreg Maybe package csquotes could be worth mentioning.